# Mysql .NET Connection String Error

Tags: mysql

My database is on online which is cheapitservice.com. The Mysql connector produces error like this:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
```

And my code is:

```
dbConn.ConnectionString = "Server=......hostedresource.com;Database=sampledb;user=user;password=test;"; dbConn.Open();
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Please help me.

mySQLconnector is version 6.6.5

Comment: Try `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`? also check if connection is allowed from the IP you are trying to connect, and any firewall blocking.

Comment: Do you have TCP connectivity to your mysql server? Try `telnet yourserveraddress 3306` (Windows) or `nc -vv yourserveraddress 3306` (*nix).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link to make works your code... [ConnectionsString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) with this you can realize whats wrong...

Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)  
               {  
   var ConnectionString = @"server=localhost; user=root; password=a54321; database=Prueba";  
   using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))  
   {  
      con.Open();  
      using (MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT IdEmpleado, Nombres, Apellidos, Correo, Telefono FROM Empleados", con))  
      using (MySqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader())  
      {  
         while (Reader.Read())  
         {  
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}",  
            Reader.GetInt32(0), Reader.GetString(1), Reader.GetString(2), Reader.GetString(3), Reader.GetString(4));  
         }  
      }  
   }  
   Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

Regards

Comment: our program is working on localhost, i think its also the same to your code but when we try to connect in online database it prompts a message "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" is there any problem in our connection string or the connector that we used???